# Alternatives to using a MovieClip or BitmapData for an image?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, oop, embed

I've been trying for two days to find an alternative to loading an image into my current project. I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS6 as my IDE and Animation program. I would like to be able to display an image in my application. What I am trying to do is have the image display onto the screen, the user enters the PLU associated with the image, and if the PLU is right then they receive a point. I have everything else already to go, but I just can't find an efficient way to deal with loading the image.
 Right now I'm using this to accomplish getting my image on the display:

```
var myDisp:Layer0 = new Layer0();
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myDisp);
spDispBox.addChild(bmp);
```

The above code works just find, but the limitation I can't get around is that I'm going to have to import each image into the library and then consecutively code each part in. I wanted to stick to OOP and streamline this process, I just don't know where I should turn to in order to accomplish my project goal. I'm more than happy to give more information. Thanks in advance, everyone.

July, 26, 2014 - Update: I agree, now, that XML is the way to go. I'm just having a hard time getting the grasp of loading an external XML file. I'm following along, but still not quite getting the idea. I understand about creating a new XML data object, Loader, and URLRequest. It's just loading the picture. I've been able to get output by using trace in the function to see that the XML is loaded, but when I go to add the XML data object to the stage I'm getting a null object reference.

I'm going to try a few more things, I just wanted to update the situation. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: You can make an XML configuration file, load it via `Loader` then iterate through that and load relevant pictures from your server. Otherwise you need to generate a bunch of code that contains `[embed ...] const LayerXX:Class;` per image, and a means to make an array out of those classes.

Comment: Thank you I will give using an XML configuration file at go. I'll post my results to let others know how it worked for me.

Comment: Depending on the size of the images. You can make a sprite sheet out of them. Then you only need to load in one image, then in code you can chop it up into the correct sections. If you have rather large images and a lot of them, this is not the best and I would go with configuration file.

Comment: you can do this with XMLs
[here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3gridgallery/) you can find out how you can do this with xml.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like these images are in your FLA library.  To simplify your code you can make a singleton class which you can name ImageFactory (factory design pattern) and call that when needing an image which will return a Sprite (lighter than a MovieClip)

```
spDispBox.addChild( ImageFactory.getImageA() ); // returns a Sprite with your image
```

and in your ImageFactory

```
public function getImageA():DisplayObject {
    var image:Layer0 = new Layer0(); // image from the FLA library
    var holder:Sprite = new Sprite();
    holder.addChild( new Bitmap( image ) );
    return holder;
}
```

also recommend using a more descriptive name than Layer0